# Insert/Replace xml into the specified node of Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XDocument:

```
<root>
  <object>
    <objectname>Schedule</objectname>
    <mode>Edit</mode>
    <row>
      <idObject>1</idObject>
      <BeginDate>2018-08-07</BeginDate>
      <EndDate>2018-08-07</EndDate>
      <TotalSum>300.17</TotalSum>
      <ScheduleOperation></ScheduleOperation>
    </row>
  </object>
</root>
```

And the following xml which I got via SelectSingleNode method of XmlDocument object:

```
<ScheduleOperation>
   <row>
      <Sum>1000.00</Sum>
      <Date>2017-09-25T00:00:00</Date>        
   </row>
</ScheduleOperation>
```

How can I insert/replace this xml into ScheduleOperation node of XDocument to get the result as follows:

```
<root>
  <object>
    <objectname>Schedule</objectname>
    <mode>Edit</mode>
    <row>
      <idObject>1</idObject>
      <BeginDate>2018-08-07</BeginDate>
      <EndDate>2018-08-07</EndDate>
      <TotalSum>300.17</TotalSum>
      <ScheduleOperation>
        <row>
          <Sum>1000.00</Sum>
          <Date>2017-09-25T00:00:00</Date>
        </row>
      </ScheduleOperation>
    </row>
  </object>
</root>
```

Comment: Learn some XSLT and you don't need to do any C# coding.

Comment: @Neil how will extensible style sheets solve this problem?

Comment: It will allow him to take 2 XML input files and merge them into 1.  Isn't that what he's asking how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956454/how-to-replace-elements-in-one-xdocument-with-elements-from-another-xdocument) I've managed to do it:

```
void Main()
{

    var initialXDoc = XDocument.Parse(Xml());   
    var emptyScheduleOperation = initialXDoc.XPathSelectElement("/root/object/row/ScheduleOperation");

    var xDocScheduleOperation = XDocument.Parse(Xml2());
    var scheduleOperation = xDocScheduleOperation.XPathSelectElement("ScheduleOperation");

    emptyScheduleOperation.ReplaceWith(scheduleOperation);
}

// initial xml:
private string Xml() => @"
<root>
  <object>
    <objectname>Schedule</objectname>
    <mode>Edit</mode>
    <row>
      <idObject>1</idObject>
      <BeginDate>2018-08-07</BeginDate>
      <EndDate>2018-08-07</EndDate>
      <TotalSum>300.17</TotalSum>
      <ScheduleOperation></ScheduleOperation>
    </row>
  </object>
</root>
";

// should be inserted into the initial xml
private string Xml2() => @"
<ScheduleOperation>
   <row>
      <Sum>1000.00</Sum>
      <Date>2017-09-25T00:00:00</Date>        
   </row>
</ScheduleOperation>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your `xdocument.xml` as:

```
<root>
  <object>
    <objectname>Schedule</objectname>
    <mode>Edit</mode>
    <row>
      <idObject>1</idObject>
      <BeginDate>2018-08-07</BeginDate>
      <EndDate>2018-08-07</EndDate>
      <TotalSum>300.17</TotalSum>
      <ScheduleOperation></ScheduleOperation>
    </row>
  </object>
</root>
```

and this `t.xslt` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/root/object/row/ScheduleOperation">
     <ScheduleOperation>
       <row>
         <Sum>1000.00</Sum>
         <Date>2017-09-25T00:00:00</Date>
       </row>
     </ScheduleOperation>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You cold use `xmlstarlet` to get the node inserted:

```
xmlstarlet tr t.xslt xdocument.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <object>
    <objectname>Schedule</objectname>
    <mode>Edit</mode>
    <row>
      <idObject>1</idObject>
      <BeginDate>2018-08-07</BeginDate>
      <EndDate>2018-08-07</EndDate>
      <TotalSum>300.17</TotalSum>
      <ScheduleOperation><row><Sum>1000.00</Sum><Date>2017-09-25T00:00:00</Date></row></ScheduleOperation>
    </row>
  </object>
</root>
```